# PayPal Error when remove setEnviroment

Tags: ios, paypal

I am implementing the PayPal SDK. Here is my code:

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId
                                                                receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail
                                                                      payerId:nil
                                                                      payment:payment
                                                                     delegate:self];
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Everything works fine but when I remove:

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
```

I get this error message:

```
 Request has failed with error:"invalid_client - System error (invalid_client). Please try again later.
details: (
        {
        "error_description" = "The client credentials are invalid";
    }
)"
```

and an alertview pops up:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I am facing similar issue, but using sandbox environment. Please can you help me out? I would be really thankful... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove "noNetwork" environment, the SDK attempts to communicate with the PayPal servers using the clientId from your code.  The default environment is production.  Make sure you are including the clientId for Live in your code.  You can also set the environment to use sandbox as well, which requires a different clientId.  You can get these clientIds at https://developer.paypal.com/